# Style Dropdown is disabled in Web 8.5 RTF Field

Tags: web8.5, rtf, format-area-styles

We migrated from SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 to Web 8.5 and when updating content in RTF field Style Drop-down is disabled.

[image: Style Drop down is disabled]

Can you please let me know how to enable Style Drop-down.

To Enable Styles we need to select "Style" check box as shown below while creating RTF field in Schema.

[image]

Is there anyway we can override the behavior of Style check box and enable globally without selecting Style Check box to get Style drop down?

In 2013 SP1 Style drop down coming without Selecting Style Check box.

Answer (score 4):

The style dropdown offers choices based on the format area stylesheet which is installed on the content management server. On an 8.5 system this is located at:

%TRIDION_HOME%\web\WebUI\Editors\Base\Configuration\FormatAreaStyles.css

For details, see the [documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-D95860F7-15DF-4091-B24E-3539F7CB33C4).

Looking at the [equivalent 2013 SP1 documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-D95860F7-15DF-4091-B24E-3539F7CB33C4), the location is given as:

\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Configuration\FormatAreaStyles.css

so you might want to pay attention to the difference between `Base` and `CME`.

The GUI caches CSS, so you may need to update the modification setting in the server config. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14654830/9967) for more information.

Obviously, during a migration, if you are moving to a new server, the stylesheet will need to be copied. So maybe you've just forgotten to copy it. If you have, you are most definitely not the first, and most probably not the last either.

Comment: After doing the above changes we started COM+ Services and Cleared Browser cache still, Style drop down is not enabled.

Comment: You may need to update the modification. I've updated the answer

Comment: After updating modification and restarted COM+ and IIS As shown in above picture if we don't select "Style" Check box, Styles are not enabled. In 2013 SP1 without selecting the Check Box Styles are enabled.

Comment: Great that you found the solution. I see that you've updated your question with the answer. I think this is a bit confusing. Perhaps you could create an answer instead. Meanwhile, I've learned something. Thanks.

Comment: Solution is same what you have given, Additionally We need to select Style Check box also while creating RTF field. Now my question is in 2013 , we no need to select Style checkbox. Is it became mandatory in Web 8.5?